# ¿Qué Implementar para guardar y recuperar información tras un Cierre de una Aplicación Java?

Tags: java, almacenamiento

Tengo Una Aplicación elaborada en Java con la IDE Netbeans, la Cual en su mayoría son formularios. Me he encontrado con el problema de que si la aplicación se cierra por alguna causa, el usuario tiene que volver a capturar toda su información. Por lo anterior he buscado sin tener éxito, que puedo hacer solucionar mi problema.

Comment: Archivos y/o bases de datos debe ser lo que estás buscando

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lo suyo sería que no tuviera fallos, que hicieran que se cerrase la aplicación, pero aún así, puedes hacer lo siguiente:

1. La información que el usuario haya escrito en la aplicación la podrías guardar, en caso de fallo, en un fichero Json, de forma estructurada. O XML, el formato que prefieras.
2. Cuando la aplicación se inicie de nuevo, comprobar si existe el fichero Json con información, para volver a cargarla en los formularios y que el usuario pueda continuar en el punto que se quedó.
3. Cuando la aplicación acabe de formar correcta, ésta debería de borrar el fichero Json o borrar su contenido.

Entiendo que tú aplicación no se conecta a una BBDD, por qué de ser lo contrario se podría guardar en una BBDD antes de cerrarse.

Comment: Si había pensado utilizar un archivo xml para recuperación, creo que el asunto puede ir por ahi

Comment: Si se conecta a una base de Datos, pero muchas veces los usuarios sufren algún percanse antes de hacer la operación que envía los datos al BD. Me surgió la duda a raíz de que hay formularios muy extensos y donde yo vivo son muy frecuentes las variaciones de voltaje, a mi como usuario me daría coraje volver a escribir todo.

Comment: Entonces la solución pasa por guardar la información de los formularios en un fichero estructurado XML o Json, eso se tiene que hacer en un try-catch... En la parte del catch. No te intesa hacer en un finally, porque siempre escribirías el fichero. Solo te interesa en caso de excepción.